# How to add the points of a grease pencil to a vertex group and set the weight of each point using Python

Tags: python, grease-pencil, vertex-groups

MY CODE IS NOT WORK, HELP ME:

import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

group = obj.vertex_groups['Bone']

p=bpy.data.grease_pencils["Stroke"].layers['Line'].frames[0].strokes[0].points[0]

group.add([p.select], 1, 'REPLACE')

Comment: Hello, check out this post demonstrating how weight is currently added to Grease Pencil points:
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/grease-pencil-vertex-group-weight-per-points/16614/2